# Python command not found while installing debian 9 from iso

Tags: debian, python, iso, setuptools

I have the following problem:
I'm running debian 9 installation from a custom created iso with additional packages. 
One of the packages runs in the postinst script a python command defined in this packages, but the postinst script fails with error:

```
my-command command not found
```

therefore all software installation step fails.
**my-package.postinst**:

```
#!/bin/bash
my-command
```

When postinst is commented out all the process finishes successfully. 
Even when the process failed ( dpkg -l return my_package in status iF) after a reboot, it is possible to run my-command from command line.
I guess the problem is in python packages which are not properly installed during running my-package.postinst, but even moving them to pre-depend did not help.
Any ideas or directions? Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance, Veronika

The custom Debian 9 iso disc is created using simple-cdd.

pkg-root/DEBIAN/control of my-package:

```
Package: my-package
Version: 1.0
Priority: optional
Architecture: all
Depends: geoip-bin, openssh-server, ntp, sshguard, lsb-release, vim, less, nload, iotop, logrotate, passwd, python-requests
Pre-depends: python, apt-transport-https, iproute2, python-setuptools
```

my-package/setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my-package',
    version='1.0',
    namespace_packages=['MyModules', 'MyModules.System'],
    packages=['MyModules.System.Tools'],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "my-command = MyModules.System.Tools:cli_my_command"
        ]
    },

    license='MyLicense'
)
```

during packaging the following command is run to create relevant entry_points,dependency_links, namespace_packages:

```
 python setup.py install -f --install-layout=deb --prefix=/usr/local --root=pkg-root
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm understanding your exact problem... But have you tried specifying the full path to `my-command` in `my-package.postinst`.

Comment: my-command defined as cli command. my-packages supposes to define it by copying my-command file into /usr/local/bin. The command is fully available **after** the package installation, even though the package itself is failed. Only during debian installation I get an error of postinst script "command not found".

Comment: After changing my-package.postinst to : #!/bin/bash python <full path to cli function> package installation runs as expected. So the problem somewhere withing python-setuptools . After the installation running cli command works

Answer (score 0):

As all python packages were installed properly, the only problem that caused not finding the cli command was in PATH variable - it did not include at this step the location of my-command (/usr/local/bin - seems it is added later).
The solution was adding this: `export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin` in my-package.postinst script before running `my-command`.